# Use AJAX and PHP to store comments permanently

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I have written a POST and GET function in javascript to send comments from input and to retrieve stored comments whenever the page is loaded. However I don't know how to handle the data that I send, how do I handle it after the data is sent to save it and then on a later point be able to access it again after a reload? So in short, send comments to server, then retrieve them on a new pageload.

I was thinking of making a storage.php file where I would handle the data and then put it to a file, but i'm not quite sure how it would work.

Here are the POST and GET functions:

```
  self.getEntries=function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"storage.php",
            dataType:'json',
            data: jsonData,
            success: function(data){
                    vm.comments=data.comments;
             }
        });
    }

 self.sendEntry=function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"storage.php",
            dataType:'json',
            data: jsonData
        });
var jsonData=ko.toJSON(ViewModel);
```

Any help or examples would be very helpful! Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: typically you'd use a database (MySQL,PostgreSQL,SQLite etc.) for that

Comment: Yes, but first i'm gonna do it with a file first just to get the hang of it all. Then i'm gonna move on to MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would want to create a PHP handler script that will take the data passed to it from your comments page, clean it up, and stick it into a database.

Then, you would create another script that fetches the data from the database and echos it back to the comments page.

I tend to see examples where people serialize the data inside of the AJAX calls before passing it to the PHP script.

Comment: Or even better, you'd use any popular framework that abstract things like that.

Comment: @bad_boy - Very true.

Comment: Working on a script now and i'm gonna use file_put_contents and serialize the data. What would I need to clean up before it goes into the file? I'm gonna work on putting it into a database later, but first I want to get it to work for a file, seems easier.

Comment: @Scatman_John - 'file_put_contents()' doesn't serialize the data, you will need to serialize it before putting it into a file.  I would highly suggest throwing them into a database over a file, but if you must you should probably just plop them into JSON objects, convert them to strings, and stick into the file with an index.  I'm guessing a file pointer would help keep you from having to read in the entire file (but rarely do I write data to a file).  That way, you can pull any single string from the file and push it back to your page easily.